Can't import python libaries in python file with PyO3
I was trying to use the pymupdf library inside Rust using PyO3. With built-in modules such as math or random then the code works. However, for libaries that I installed using pip into .venv then it doesn't work. I am using python 3.12
Here is my code
main.rs
use pyo3::prelude::*;

fn main() -> PyResult<()> {
    let pdf_py = include_str!(concat!(env!("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR"), "/python_app/pdf_op.py"));

    let from_python = Python::with_gil(|py| -> PyResult<Py<PyAny>> {
        let app: Py<PyAny> = PyModule::from_code_bound(py, pdf_py, "", "")?
            .getattr("hello")?
            .into();

        app.call0(py)
    });

    println!("py: {}", from_python?);

    Ok(())
}

Cargo.toml
name = "pyo3_test"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
pyo3 = { version = "0.21.2", features = ["extension-module", "auto-initialize"] }

pdf_op.py
import fitz


def hello():
    return "Hello world"


I ensured that I downloaded pymupdf into env by following the pymupdf documentation:


Please do not post images of text. Post them as text.

Note that you usually don't need both extension-module and auto-initialize. In your case, you only need the later.

In short, your code run in the global Python, not in your venv.
